# android getDrawable() doesn't run

Tags: android, mobile, drawable

I am trying to make an app to turn on mobile data on click. However, it requires to detect if mobile data is already on. If it is already on, data1.png is displayed else data0.png. However, for some reason it is not changing. TEST 2 is running though. (wdata is Image Button) This is the code:

```
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try {
        Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
        Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
        method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
        // get the setting for "mobile data"
        mobEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(cm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Some problem accessible private API
        // TODO do whatever error handling you want here
    }
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+mobEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

IF MOBILE DATA IS ENABLED, IT RETURNS TRUE.

```
    if(mobEnabled){
        wdata1=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.data1);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ":Test 1:"+mobEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //RUNS

        wdata.setImageDrawable(wdata1);// DOESN'T SET

    }else{
        wdata1 =
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.data0);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ":Test 2:"+mobEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        wdata.setImageDrawable(wdata1);

    }
```

I have used the Drawable wdata1 in other areas:

```
        wdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext())){
                setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), false);
                wdata1 =
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.data0);
                amobileDataEnabled = false;



            }else{
                setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(),true);
                wdata1 =
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.data1);
                amobileDataEnabled = true;

            }
            wdata.setImageDrawable(wdata1);
        }
    });
```

And in the onResume() method:

```
   if( amobileDataEnabled){
        wdata1 =
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.data1);
        wdata.setImageDrawable(wdata1);

    }else {
        wdata1 =
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.data0);
       wdata.setImageDrawable(wdata1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting a drawable to something else, try calling `wdata.invalidateDrawable(wdata1);` right afterwards to indicate it needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Not working. When the mobile data is on and oncreate() starts, the image needs to be data1.png, however the image is set to data0.png by default. :Test 2:True is diplayed ,but image doesn't change.

Comment: I got the solution myself. Thank you for answering. :)

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer for anyone who sees this question.

Comment: We need to put the first block of code in a seperate function and return the boolean value. Then it works fine :)